# GDB terminated unexpectedly

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a code on Qt 5.0,but when i try to debug it an error message window appears saying "GDB process terminated unexpectedly (code 0)" along with the blank console output window.
I searched for it on google,got some answers like unchecking run terminal etc but they didn't work.
Can anyone suggest me something about this?

Debugger Log:

```
THE FOLLOWING COMMAND CHECKS AVAILABLE FEATURES. AN ERROR IS EXPECTED.
<134-interpreter-exec console "disassemble 0 0"
dEXAMINING D:/projects_qt/build-contractfile-gdb-Debug/debug/contractfile
dELF SECTIONS: 
dNO SECTION HEADERS FOUND. IS THIS AN EXECUTABLE?
sSetting up inferior...
<135set substitute-path C:/iwmake/build_mingw_opensource D:/QtInstall/5.0.2/Src
<136set substitute-path C:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src D:/QtInstall/5.0.2/Src
<137set substitute-path Q:/qt5_workdir/w/s D:/QtInstall/5.0.2/Src
<138-interpreter-exec console "set auto-solib-add on"
<139-interpreter-exec console "python print 43"
<140-interpreter-exec console "pwd"
dGDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 0, code 0
dNOTE: ENGINE ILL ******
dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineShutdownRequested(20) [master]
dQUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE

dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN IN STATE 1, PROC: 0
dNOTE: ENGINE SHUTDOWN OK
dState changed from EngineShutdownRequested(20) to EngineShutdownOk(22) [master]
dState changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23) [master]
dQUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dNOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dHANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
sDebugger finished.
```

Comment: Did you try to run the application without GDB? I had a similar problem, but it was because a shared library was missing in the path so that the application couldn't be loaded.

Comment: unfortunately my cdb also don't work...:-(

Comment: What is your compilation line ?

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn: sorry...what you mean by compilation line?

Comment: How do you compile the program ? What is the command ?

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn:I just debug my program from debug option in Qt...I'm using VC++ compiler

Comment: Take a look at the ``compilation`` tab located on the bottom. Copy/Paste the ``g++ -L...`` line and also see if on tab ``Application Output`` some more information is written.

Comment: @SebastianLange: at application output its showing only:Debugging starts
Debugging has finished. But where is compilation tab located in Qt5.0.2

Comment: Eventually you need to enable it with the two arrows beside the labes on the bottom. Did you set an breakpoint in you application? Try setting a breakpoint within your mainwindows contructor or even in main-function.

Comment: @SebastianLange: I have edited my question and added debugger log that may give you some idea,and breakpoint doesn't help.

Comment: Does your code eventually not open any UI-Elements or does it quit automatically?

Comment: console window is appearing but blank no output...it stays there till i close it.